# Group by field select property using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object `Record`

It contains the following properties:

`Guid RecordId`

`User User`

`Guid UserId`

Now I have to make a grouping and use this Linq query:

`Records.GroupBy(m => m.User)`

Problem is that the `User` object is filled from 2 places and sometimes the data is not matched property, resulting in having multiple results for a single `UserId`

For example:

```
List<Record> 
{
    new Record 
    {
        RecordId = 1,
        User = new User 
        {
            UserId = 1,
            UserName = '1',
            OtherProperty = false
        }
        UserId = 1
    },
    new Record 
    {
        RecordId = 2,
        User = new User 
        {
            UserId = 1,
            UserName = '1',
            OtherProperty = true
        }
        UserId = 1
    },
    new Record 
    {
        RecordId = 3,
        User = new User 
        {
            UserId = 2,
            UserName = '2',
            OtherProperty = false
        }
        UserId = 2
    }
}
```

The `OtherProperty` is different in the `User` objects, resulting in nothing being grouped.

I need a grouping by the `User` object BUT actually using the `UserId` as the grouping field.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Records.GroupBy(m => m.User.UserId)
```

GUIDs are fairly unique, so you should be able to all-but-certainly match (and thus group by) users, simply by comparing their IDs.

As an alternative, this might be a simpler solution:

```
Records.GroupBy(m => m.UserId)
```

Note, however, that this will only work if you are enforcing that the `UserId` property of a given `Record` object must match the `UserId` property of the `User` object belonging to said `Record` object.

**Side Note:** In your OP, you mentioned that a mismatch in data can result in there being `User` objects with the same `UserId`. If you are looking to merge the "duplicates" (i.e., some properties may be different, but the `UserId` is the same), the `GroupBy` method will help you to organize the records for each user. However, if the records all have the same properties, you may be interested in using the `Distinct` method, as it may be passed a lambda and can be used to select one `Record` object for each `UserId` that is present.

Comment: Problem is that this is what I have now: `IEnumerable<IGrouping<User, Record>>`, but with your method I get this result: `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Guid, Record>>`. I lose the `User` key. I would like to have the `User` as a key but with the `UserId` as groupby selector.

Comment: If that is the case, then you need to write the equality comparison for a `User` to be (in pseudo): `return u1.UserID == u2.UserID;`. After you do that, you will be able to `GroupBy` the `User`.

Comment: May I ask why, if you have the `Record` as the value and the `Record` contains the `User`, you want to have the user, itself, be the grouping key?

Comment: The example ofcourse is simplified, but it is a fairly complex joined table which contains the `UserId` PK which EF joines the table to. Problem is that I get the query, with records&users, load it in cache and then add new records with `User` objects. The `User` object (table) contains many fields and again joined tables, which are not all used so there might be small differences in the `User` objects in the list.

Comment: I don't have much more time to put into this, but, IMHO, I would say that, in general, you should not be caching things that are dynamic and not static.

Comment: I'd love to know what led to me getting a downvote for this post :/